# Уведомить нескольких пользователей в комментарии

Tags: поддержка, комментарии

Как удалось написать [этот комментарий](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/731446/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-getboundingclientrect-js/731453#comment1110377_731446)? У меня получается уведомлять только одного пользователя, а при нескольких показывается ошибка:

> [image: скриншот]

Comment: так было ж уже. если поставить апостроф в конце сообщения ругаться прекратит, но не уверен, что отправит уведомление всем

Comment: @Grundy, не читал такого. Но я уведомление получил.

Comment: @Grundy, @Qwertiy проверка связи`

Comment: @Андрей, мне пришло.

Comment: @Андрей, плохая проверка, потому что @Qwertiy и так получит оповещение`

Comment: @Qwertiy, давай лучше ты попробуй сразу мне и ему. Но в вопросе действительно интересно как так получилось

Comment: @Grundy, тем более в его нике опечатка была ) Надо позвать еще кого-то для проверки

Comment: @Андрей, @Grundy - проверка.`

Comment: @Qwertiy, я получил

Comment: А я нет........

Comment: @Grundy, @Андрей - а так? `

Comment: а так да, :-) .

Comment: А тот комментарий все получили, я потом подумал что получит уведомление только @Qwertiy

Comment: @Qwertiy А я нет

Comment: @Qwertiy я тоже пытаюсь назвать несколько, но у меня после того как я тебя назвал другие имена даже не выводятся, что бы кликнуть их и вызвать

Comment: @Андрей, @Qwertiy вот так пришлось "Qwertiy" вписать в ручную`

Comment: Видимо получает только первый.

Comment: @Air, остальных надо руками копипастить)

Comment: у меня тоже без апострофа ругался а с отправил сообщение

Comment: @Qwertiy, это я уже понял что руками))))

Comment: Nofate комментарии перенес

Comment: @alexolut, какие и куда?

Comment: @Qwertiy на который ссылка в вопросе вестимо